# Google Maps: how to fix problem when printing maps?

Tags: javascript, maps

So I'm trying to print google maps map and the problem I have is when trying to zoom in the map and then print it the map is really small and barely visible in Firefox
[Firefox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntoJZ.png)

In Chrome the problem is that it prints too many empty pages. I only need the first one because the map is on the first, here I get 5 pages:
[Chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdtDt.png)

My code is this:

```
function printMap() {
const body = $('body');
const mapContainer = $('#map');
const mapContainerParent = mapContainer.parent();
const printContainer = $('<div style="position: relative;">');

printContainer
    .height(mapContainer.height())
    .append(mapContainer)
    .prependTo(body);

const content = body
    .children()
    .not(printContainer)
    .not('script')
    .detach();

const patchedStyle = $('<style media="print">')
    .text(`
    img {max-width: none !important}
  a[href]:after { content: ""; }
  @page{
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
`)
    .appendTo('head');

window.print();

body.prepend(content);
mapContainerParent.prepend(mapContainer);

printContainer.remove();
patchedStyle.remove();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After long search and attempts I found a way to fix the problem with printing the full size of the map for all browsers..

```
function printMap() {
$('<style media="print">')
    .text(`
   body {
    width: ${screen.width}px;
    height: ${screen.height}px;
  }
  body { zoom: 50% !important;}
  @page {margin: 0 !important; size: letter !important}
`)
    .appendTo('head');

window.print();
return false;
```

}